# Spacing process virtual memory pages evenly accross interleaved memory

Tags: linux, multithreading, memory, memory-management, powerpc

This question is about DRAM speeds and memory interleaving. I have a very specific problem. I am using a power based architecture board (minus the AltiVec) and I wish to copy a large segment of memory (virtual contiguous) between two regions within my process' address space. To offset the slowness of my core, I affixed two threads to two cpu's and that made copy a lot faster.

However that was still *not fast enough*. so I added a third thread, and it made no difference to copy times whatsoever. I did more research on this and found that my board was equipped with a single DDR3 RAM (speed 1600 MB/s) and it was pretty close to max attainable speeds already.

[ Some explanation here: With just 2 threads, I am copying, say 5500 pages of size 4K in around 16.5 milliseconds. If you do a simple calculation, it would seem that the minimum time in theory that you could clock (bar all prefetches and stuff) is 13.75 milliseconds. ]

I discovered that I could add an extra RAM to my board. Which I could possibly get my co. to fund by telling them I also intend to halve the size of each stick of memory, but how can I get the kernel to allocate me memory that is *guaranteed* to be evenly distributed across both memories?

Thanks a lot for answering!

P.s. I am using linux kernel version 2.6.34.

Comment: This may be better suited for http://superuser.com/

Comment: Ok. Any way I could migrate it there?

Comment: Does it have to be a copy? If it's a move, you can play with the page table and move data without touching the data. I had a question about that a while ago: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2679065/321772 . If it needs to be a copy, maybe you can do copy-on-write on that architecture?

Comment: @Adam, yeah I'm afraid it has to be a copy.. I see what you mean, though - like remap the physical memory to a different virtual address in the process execution space?

Comment: You got it. It might be possible to map a single physical page to multiple virtual pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if your Linux / board combination supports the NUMA (Non-uniform memory access) extensions. You can specify interleaving policies through [libnuma](http://linux.die.net/man/3/numa):

> The libnuma library offers a simple programming interface to the NUMA
>   (Non Uniform Memory Access) policy supported by the Linux kernel. On a
>   NUMA architecture some memory areas have different latency or
>   bandwidth than others.
>   
>   **Available policies are page interleaving** (i.e., allocate in a
>   round-robin fashion from all, or a subset, of the nodes on the
>   system), preferred node allocation (i.e., preferably allocate on a
>   particular node), local allocation (i.e., allocate on the node on
>   which the task is currently executing), or allocation only on specific
>   nodes (i.e., allocate on some subset of the available nodes). It is
>   also possible to bind tasks to specific nodes.

Comment: Thank you. I am not very familiar with much of NUMA but I guess it is rtfm for me :)

Comment: And yes, I think my board does support NUMA.

Comment: @AnirbanGhoshal If this does end up helping you out, be sure to mark the answer, and maybe provide some edits to your question that show exactly how you used it to solve your problem, so that people in the future that have this same problem can find your solution.

Comment: Sorry, spoilsport that I am, but it seems my co. would not allow me the dual memory banks after all. It seems they have already pre-ordered a large number of boards with a single bank of memory, and so this is out. Thank you everyone for all your suggestions, though, at least I came to know a few stuff about NUMA this way!